# Laravel eloquent join three joins using find

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi I am looking to use Eloquent to join three Eloquent models in order to retrieve the assigned `statuses` `name` from a `project` which will be held in the `assigned_project_board_statuses`. The `assigned_project_board_statuses` table has two foreign keys the table schema is below:

`id|project_id|status_id|order|created_at|updated_at`

`project_id` and `status_id` are the foreign keys.

The models I have are:

`Project` (table name `projects`), `Status` (tables name: `statuses`) and `AssignedProjectBoardStatus` (table name: `assigned_project_board_statuses`).

I can retrieve the assigned statuses to a project by doing the following:

`Project::find(3)->assignedProjectBoardStatuses;`

app/models/Project.php

```
public function assignedProjectBoardStatuses() {
        return $this->hasMany('AssignedProjectBoardStatus','project_id')->orderBy('order','asc');
    }
```

app/models/AssignedProjectBoardStatus.php

```
public function projects() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Project');
}
public function statuses() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Status');
}
```

app/models/Status.php

```
public function assignedProjectBoardStatus() {
        return $this->hasMany('AssignedProjectBoardStatus');
}
```

Any ideas how I can extend this to also join the `status` model too as I would ideally like to retrieve the `name` and order field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eagerly load all related models:

```
$project = Project::with(['assignedProjectBoardStatuses', 'assignedProjectBoardStatuses.statuses'])->find(3);
```

Now you have access to collection of **AssignedProjectBoardStatus** in

```
$project->assignedProjectBoardStatuses
```

and on each of them you can access the **Status** using

```
$project->assignedProjectBoardStatuses[0]->status
```